# How to use .on() function for this situation

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

At the top of my application the user is able to choose their options and answers and then they can store their options and answers in a new table row.

What my question is how can I have each and every row to perform the same functionality as the options and answers features above so that if the user changes their mind on changing an option or answer in a particular row, they can change it within the row.

My code is on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C443c/26/). Please follow the steps below if you want to be able to use the options and answers feature in the fiddle.

1. Open grid and select option "3". "3" is displayed in textbox and buttons A to C are displayed below.
2. Type in number 2 in the Number of Answers textbox. This means only 2 buttons can be selected between buttons A to C.
3. Select buttons A and B, if you try to select another button an alert would appear stating you are beyond limit.
4. Click on "Add Question" button and a row would be created showing your details.

I want all of the functionality in each column to match the functionality of the options and answers feature on top. I know I need to use the `.on()` function but how can I include this for each row?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to know how to reuse the "alert" on step "3" in regard to the table rows..

Then you are correct - "on" is the function you want. ( this function deprecate the [live function](http://api.jquery.com/live/) )
What "on" does is re-evaluate the selector on each event.

Instead of assigning the "onclick" event in

```
<input class="answerBtns" name="answerAName" id="answerA" type="button" value="A" onclick="btnclick(this);"/>
```

You should write the following

```
$(".answerBtns").on("click",btnclick);
```

This will effectively bind the "btnclick" method on every ".answerBtns" element this page has or will have (present and future) - since the selector $(".answerBtns") will be re-evaluated on each click.

Now all that is left is to generalize the "btnclick" function to support the all scenarios. Which means it has to identify if it is in a row or in the form and behave appropriately.

For example (unchecked, but not pseudo code):

```
<script>
  function btnclick(){
      if ( $(this).closest("#qandatbl").length > 0 ) {  // we are in the table because we are wrapped in a table
           var myRow = $(this).closest("tr");
           var ourLimit = myRow.find(".numberAnswerTxtRow").val();
           if ( myRow.find(".answerBtnsOn").length > ourLimit ){
                 alert("...");... 
           }
      }else{...} // we are not in a table.. lets do what we always did. 
  }
</script>
```

As you can see, I used [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) because they give me same functionality but only relative to the click origin.

Let me know if I missed something and I will add it.